# Gradle: How to invoke webpack bundle the built files into a jar file?

Tags: gradle, webpack

I have a frontend project using webpack. There is no java code in the project to be compiled. I want gradle to do 2 things:

1. Invoke webpack build, generate the frontend build.
2. Pickup the generated build files, and put them into a jar under the location `/META-INF/resources`

The important part to note is that this is not a java project.